# Crashlytics proguard issue - can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, android-proguard

I have integrated `crashlytics` in my app and found issue related to `proguard` rules while building release `apk`.

> Warning: com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics: can't find referenced
>   class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics: can't find referenced class
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics: can't find referenced class
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics: can't find referenced class
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics: can't find referenced class
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics$Builder: can't find referenced
>   class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics$Builder: can't find referenced
>   class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics$Builder: can't find referenced
>   class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics$Builder: can't find referenced
>   class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics$Builder: can't find referenced
>   class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't find
>   referenced class
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.AppMeasurementEventLogger Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't find
>   referenced class
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.AppMeasurementEventLogger Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't find
>   referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't find
>   referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't find
>   referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers Warning:
>   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't find
>   referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.EventLogger
>   Warning:   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't
>   find referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.EventLogger
>   Warning:   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't
>   find referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.EventLogger
>   Warning:   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't
>   find referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers
>   Warning:   com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController: can't
>   find referenced class   com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers  ....
>       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

My proguard rules exist in `proguard-project.txt` are

```
# for Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*
```

Adding : `-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**` leads to crash in app

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers" on path: DexPathList

I don't know what is missing in rules.

Comment: try to remove android and use this -> -dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
        -keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }

Comment: @Shane App build successfully but leads to run time crash of `apk` when it launches : `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers"`